# Decoding then encoding a jpeg file will cause the output to be rotated if there is Orientation exif metadata on the source jpeg

Tags: python, tensorflow

The example here is a stripped-down version of an upscaling program I wrote while trying to learn how to use Tensorflow. If I feed it an image that has orientation exif metadata (my test image has Rotate 270 CW) then the output image will be rotated as if to "correct" that orientation. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, either by passing in a flag or value to the decode_jpeg / encode_jpeg functions, or by stripping out the metadata beforehand?

```
"Use tensorflow to decode then encode an image at a hard-coded location and save the result to a second hard-coded location."

import tensorflow as tf

def main():
    "Use tensorflow to decode then encode an image at a hard-coded location and save the result to a second hard-coded location."

    sess = tf.Session()
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file('D:\\TensorFlow\\Upscaling\\C890FAA477.jpg'), channels=3)
    fname = tf.constant('D:\\TensorFlow\\Upscaling\\C890FAA477_DEC_ENC.jpg')
    enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.uint8))
    fwrite = tf.write_file(fname, enc)
    sess.run(fwrite)
    return

main()
```

Comment: (Without much experience, some random-guess:) Are you sure it's interpreting that exif-metadata? I would think, that it decodes that image as is, but not doing the rotation. Meaning, that every app showing the image nicely has rotated it. (Interpreting this kind of data makes no sense to me in ML-applications and adds a new layer of potential problems. This is why i would think, decoding is not caring about those rotations).

Comment: @sascha I was just coming here to say that. Windows file browser and photo viewer were automatically applying the rotation, and also flipping the width / height values to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had this all backward. Both Windows Explorer and the default photo viewer were automatically applying the rotation, and they were flipping the width / height values to match the new rotation. Nothing to do with Python or Tensorflow.